# SonarScanner can run on linux but no result? (.NET Core 2)

Tags: .net-core, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to use Gitlab CI with SonarQube.

It can run successfully under the situation:

**1. Ubuntu VM**

```
● docker(SonarQube) 1.13.1

● sonar-gitlab-plugin 3.0.0
```

**2. Windows 7 local**

```
● gitlab-runner 10

● SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.3.1

● .NET Core 2.0
```

However, it cannot produce results when SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild running on Ubuntu too.
[click for no-results picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXpPf.png)

Is it possible to do use the sonar scanner on Ubuntu? Like this:

**Ubuntu VM**

```
● docker(SonarQube) 1.13.1

● sonar-gitlab-plugin 3.0.0

● gitlab-runner 10

● SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.3.1

● .NET Core 2.0
```

I have searched that in this page, it indicated it can. 
But it's not working on me.
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Install+the+SonarScanner+for+MSBuild